# Kendo Grid UI Watermark column or two drop down lists for one column

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am trying to use Kendo UI grid to represent a string which is usually stored as something like this:
"ww12'14" as a string in my datasource. This format is for work week 12, year 2014.

When in edit mode, I would like to give the user two drop down lists. One for available week options and one for available years. How can I accomplish this?

Another way I could do this is to use a water mark in edit mode. For example when you edit in this column I would like a text box to become available which has a watermark set on it. This will force your input to be two integers, followed by two more integers and automatically fill in w, w, ' while the user inputs the 2, two digit integer values. This will force the user input to always be valid.

Any ideas how I can accomplish either of the two feats using Kendo UI Grid?

Cheers and thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

There's a jQuery plugin that you could use to implement alternative #2: https://github.com/digitalBush/jquery.maskedinput

For alternative #1:
I would create a popup for this since two dropdowns take up a lot of space, i.e. instead of putting a control into the grid cell when editing, you could open a modal kendoWindow, put the two dropdown widgets in it and OK/Cancel buttons. Bind a function to the OK button which updates the grid dataItem.

Skeleton code:

```
editor: function (container, options) {
    var row = $(container).closest("tr");
    var dataItem = grid.dataItem(row);

    // create window etc.
    var windowHtml = ...
    $(windowHtml).kendoWindow({
        .... options
    });

    // handler to set the value
    $(container).on("click", okButtonSelector, function () {
        var weekValue = ddl1.value();
        var yearValue = ddl2.value();
        var packed = weekValue + "'" + yearValue;
        dataItem.set(columnName, packed);

        // destroy the window ...
        ...
    });
}
```